# Ramda - Convert array of objects into object

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

Looked around but couldn't find an answer to this.

Is there a more declarative way of doing this with `ramda`?

```
R.reduce((acc, val) => { 
  acc[val.name] = val.value
  return acc
}, {}, fields)
```

Basically, I am converting an array that looks like this:

```
[
   { name: "firstName", value: "John" }, 
   { name: "lastName", value: "Doe" }
]
```

Into a single object that looks like this:

```
{ firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" }
```

Comment: While OriDrori's Ramda answer may be slightly more readable, note that this is pretty clear with vanilla JS: `const convert = (xs) => Object .fromEntries (xs .map (({name, value}) => [name, value]))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Map the the array into an array of `[name, value]` pairs, and then convert it to an object using R.fromPairs:

```js
const { pipe, fromPairs, map, props } = R

const fn = pipe(map(props(['name', 'value'])), fromPairs)

const arr = [{ name: "firstName", value: "John" }, {name: "lastName", value: "Doe" }]

const result = fn(arr)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

With vanilla JS you can create the array of pairs (entries) by mapping the array, using destructuring, and then converting to object using `Object.fromEntries()`:

```js
const fn = arr => Object.fromEntries(arr.map(({ name, value }) => [name, value]))

const arr = [{ name: "firstName", value: "John" }, {name: "lastName", value: "Doe" }]

const result = fn(arr)

console.log(result)
```